# Typing in Command line (cmd.exe) is very slow

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

Text input from my keyboard in command line is very slow. The blink rate is also very slow as well. Using Win xp Sp3. Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: What is your processor and hard disk usage like?

Comment: It's just normal. Task manager shows 92% Idle processor.

Comment: Yes I did restarted

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/a/454544 ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google brings up a blog post describing a [possible solution to a similar problem](http://jordan.liggitt.net/2008/05/14/very-slow-typing-in-cmdexe/) if you are using a Lenovo Laptop.  Try disabling IPS Core Service, a process [apparently used by Lenovo](http://www.file.net/process/ipssvc.exe.html) in their laptops (see comments on that link).

To disable the service, first kill it in the task manager, and then run msconfig from your command prompt, go to the Services tab, and disable IPS Core Service.  You may need to reboot before the problem will be fixed.

Comment: My laptop is not from Lenovo, it's Acer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting to grips with the Microsoft Windows Sysinternals application [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Its pretty technical but if you do your research properly and take the time you will be able to use it to find the cause.