# Command prompt takes 7-8 seconds to load in Windows 7

Tags: shell, windows-7, command-line

When I go to Run and type cmd, it takes about 7-8 seconds for the command prompt to appear.

I have a Core i5 with 3GB of RAM running Windows 7 x86.

I really need the command prompt to run instantly because I use a lot of scripts to improve productivity. When the command prompt itself takes 7 seconds to load, the whole point is lost.

Does anyone have ideas as to what might be causing these delays?

Comment: If your goal is efficiency, why not pin the command prompt to the taskbar and start it with `Win`+`Number` hotkeys or a single mouse click?

Comment: As @OliverSalzburg suggested you is the best way but still we need little bit more information as this happens only when you launch the 'cmd' through Run command or the same problem when you launch it from the start menu?

Comment: thank you for the answers. My issue is that cmd takes a long time to load, whether i load it through Run, or even by double clicking on cmd.exe or even if i execute any batch file. are there any monitoring tools i can use to check what's going on under the hood when cmd loads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).
2. Filter the output such that you're only looking at a **Process Name** of `conhost.exe` or `cmd.exe`.

   [image]
3. Add the **Duration** column to the output.

   [image]
   [image]
4. Fire up a `cmd.exe` and see what's going on.

Comment: Nice edit, Oliver!

Comment: /@Oliver Salzburg. Wow, thanks you so much for a great answer. I will try these out now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to your home drive.  If you open cmd.exe and by default it takes you to a mapped network drive, that could be the issue.

Basically, when I was connected via a VPN that didn't allow my on-site network mappings, cmd.exe would take a good ~10 seconds to open up.

Answer (score 0):

user810816 had the correct answer for me. On VPN, I had a lag of up to 50 seconds before CMD would even open.

On the start menu, right click to show file location, then right click again and edit the properties to "start in" a local drive, such as c:. The default variables resulted in a slow-to-access network location...

The load time is now almost instantaneous.